# How to Map each cell in a matrix to another and solve the system?

Tags: equation-solving, map

```
tab1 = {{a1, a1 + a2}, {b1, b2*b2}}
tab2 = {{2, 5}, {5, 2}}
```

I want to map like this

```
Table[tab1[[i, j]] == tab2[[i, j]], {i, 2}, {j, 2}]
Solve[Flatten[%]]
```

I wonder if there is a more efficient way? or short cuts?

Thanks!

Comment: In version 9 you do not need to do anything extra. `Solve[tab1 == tab2]` works fine for me.
`{{a2 -> 3, b1 -> 5, a1 -> 2, b2 -> -Sqrt[2]}, {a2 -> 3, b1 -> 5, 
  a1 -> 2, b2 -> Sqrt[2]}}`

Comment: @yashar good one, go for the Accept :D

Comment: @yashar @yves I can confirm that in V10.0.1 works fine as well. I am really new to MMA. It's just that `tab1 == tab2` does not seem to be the 'normal' format one would use to supply to `Solve`. So I did not try that! But it works just fine!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since version 9 you do not need to do anything extra.

```
tab1 = {{a1, a1 + a2}, {b1, b2*b2}}
tab2 = {{2, 5}, {5, 2}}
Solve[tab1 == tab2]
{{a2 -> 3, b1 -> 5, a1 -> 2, b2 -> -Sqrt[2]}, {a2 -> 3, b1 -> 5, a1 -> 2, b2 -> Sqrt[2]}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) for this purpose:

```
eqs = MapThread[Equal, {tab1, tab2}, 2]

(*{{a1 == 2, a1 + a2 == 5}, {b1 == 5, b2^2 == 2}}*)

Solve[Flatten[eqs]]

(*{{a2 -> 3, b1 -> 5, a1 -> 2, b2 -> -Sqrt[2]},
   {a2 -> 3, b1 -> 5, a1 -> 2, b2 -> Sqrt[2]}}*)
```